# Mongoose not bringing in any results

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to build a kind of complex query in mongoose, my problem is all the parameters this query can receive are non mandatory and that is bringing me problems. Right now I did this:

```
let query = {
            publicationType: req.body.searchParams.publicationType
        };
        if (req.body.searchParams.address) {
            query.address = {};
            if (req.body.searchParams.address.city) {
                query.address.city = req.body.searchParams.address.city;
            }
        }
        try {
            const dwellings = await model.Dwelling.find({
                $and: [{$or: [{publicationType: req.body.searchParams.publicationType}]},
                    {
                        $or: [{
                            address: [query.address]
                        }]
                    }]
            }).lean().exec();
            console.log(dwellings);
            res.send({dwellings});
        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
    });
```

This was to try out if the city parameter is working, if I search only by publication type I get the desired results, if I add city I get 0 results even when I'm supposed to get more, I debugged mongoose to see how the query was being built and it's like this:

```
Mongoose: dwelling.find({ '$and': [ { '$or': [ { publicationType: 'Venta' } ] }, { '$or': [ { address: { '$in': [ { city: 'La Plata' } ] } } ] } ] }, { fields: {} })
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are building an [**$and** expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) of two [**$or** expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) *but* each **$or** expression has only one argument each, so you are effectively building this **$and** `find` expression (note, I'm using the `mongo` shell syntax below):

```
db.dwellings.find({ 
   '$and': [ 
       { publicationType: 'Venta' }, 
       { address: { '$in': [ { city: 'La Plata' } ] } } 
   ]
});
```

... in words: "find the dwellings with publicationType `Venta` **and** `address.city` `La Plata`.

> if I add city I get 0 results even when I'm supposed to get more

Since you mention you expect to get more results when you add in `address.city` I suspect you really want the top-level expression to be `$or` not `$and`, like this:

```
db.dwellings.find({ 
   '$or': [ 
       { publicationType: 'Venta' }, 
       { address: { '$in': [ { city: 'La Plata' } ] } } 
   ]
});
```

You may want to experiment more with your query in `mongo` shell before expressing it as code. If you happen to have Docker available on your workstation, I find running `mongo` in a container a useful way to prototype things while developing, for example:

```
docker run --name mongo -d mongo:3.7
# after mongo is up and running...
docker exec -it mongo mongo
```

In the interactive mongo shell you can insert documents for testing and experiment with `find` expressions, example:

```
use stackoverflow;
dwell1 = { publicationType: 'Venta', address: { city: 'Somewhere' } };
dwell2 = { publicationType: 'Something', address: { city: 'La Plata' } };
db.dwellings.insert(dwell1);
db.dwellings.insert(dwell2);

# Try results of $and
db.dwellings.find({ '$and': [ 
   { publicationType: 'Venta' }, 
   { address: { '$in': [ { city: 'La Plata' } ] } } 
]  });

# ... compare to results of $or
db.dwellings.find({ '$or': [ 
   { publicationType: 'Venta' }, 
   { address: { '$in': [ { city: 'La Plata' } ] } } 
]  });
```

... once you have inserted some documents for testing, confirm whether you want an `$and` or `$or` expression in your `find`.

Comment: This was very helpfull but it still not working, my first problem is i want to finde dwellings with publicationType: Venta AND address.city  la plata But i might not get the address and get only the publication type. Second i tried out the first AND example you showed me and still brings 0 results  the only way it seem to work is if i ask like this {"address.city": 'La Plata'}

Comment: with this 'address.city': req.body.searchParams.address ? (req.body.searchParams.address.city ? req.body.searchParams.address.city : '') : ''  the problem with that is that if i get no address it searchs documents with city = ''

Answer (score 0):

so with the guidness of drew Maclnnis i figured out how to make it work at least

```
const query = {};
        if (req.body.searchParams.publicationType !== '') {
            query['publicationType'] = req.body.searchParams.publicationType;
        }
        if (req.body.searchParams.address) {
            if (req.body.searchParams.address.streetNumber !== undefined) {
                query['address.streetNumber'] = req.body.searchParams.address.streetNumber;
            }
            if (req.body.searchParams.address.streetName !== undefined) {
                query['address.streetName'] = req.body.searchParams.address.streetName;
            }
            if (req.body.searchParams.address.city !== undefined) {
                query['address.city'] = req.body.searchParams.address.city;
            }
            if (req.body.searchParams.address.state !== undefined) {
                query['address.state'] = req.body.searchParams.address.state;
            }
            if (req.body.searchParams.address.country !== undefined) {
                query['address.country'] = req.body.searchParams.address.country;
            }
            if (req.body.searchParams.address.zip !== undefined) {
                query['address.zip'] = req.body.searchParams.address.zip;
            }
        }
        if (req.body.searchParams.price) {
            if (req.body.searchParams.price.min !== undefined) {
                query['price'] = {$gt: req.body.searchParams.price.min};
            }
            if (req.body.searchParams.price.max !== undefined) {
                query['price'] = {$lt: req.body.searchParams.price.max};
            }
        }
        try {
            const dwellings = await model.Dwelling.find({
                '$and': [
                    query
                ]
            }).lean().exec();
            console.log(dwellings);
            res.send({dwellings});
        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
```

can this be optimized?